# rspec: How to test redis#subscribe code?

Tags: ruby, rspec, redis, publish-subscribe

Given something like:

```
class MyClass
  def subscribe
    $redis.subscribe('channel') do |on|
       on.message do |channel, msg|
         Something.create(msg)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I test that when `MyClass` executes `subscribe`, it will run `Something.create` for each message it receives on the channel?

Comment: Why do you use `$redis` as a global variable?

Comment: Theoratically speaking you have two ways to do this: 1- Mocking Redis object 2- Test if msg was published to channel.

Comment: Alexey: to make it easier to understand the code, in my real code, it is @store but then I would have to put the init code in the sample and I wanted to have a bare bone use case.

Comment: @moeabdol : mock_redis does not support the pubsub features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code you have, it's not very testable. First of all, absolutely get rid of this global `$redis` variable. Instead, accept an instance of redis in the constructor.

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :redis

  def initialize(redis)
    @redis = redis
  end

  def subscribe
    redis.subscribe('channel') do |on|
       on.message do |channel, msg|
         Something.create(msg)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in tests you can make a dummy redis that you can totally control but which conforms to the api you're using. Something along these lines:

```
class DummyRedis
  def subscribe(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def trigger_on
    @block.call make_on_message
  end
end


fake_redis = DummyRedis.new

expect {
  mc = MyClass.new(fake_redis)
  mc.subscribe
  fake_redis.trigger_on
}.to change{Something.count}.from(0).to(1)
```

This cool technique is called Dependency Injection (or, as some people put it, "passing parameters to constructors").

Comment: I know all about DI, I used to do it a lot, but with rspec `allow` I find that I only use it as a last resort (which may be the case here) because I dont like to add complexity when it is onyl justified to make tests easier.

Comment: Ah, ok then. I'll be deleting my answer shortly :)

Comment: Well, DI has other benefits too, besides facilitating testing. Most important, reducing coupling.

Comment: Nah, I decided to go that way since it seems to be the only reasonable approach in my case. BTW, I am a big fan of DI, I just find that it tends to make the code base & complexity grow too fast for simple use case. But sometimes, it is the only way to test.

Comment: BTW, what is your make_on_message method? Can't figure out how to manage the `on.message` part

Comment: Well, that's a fill-in-the-blanks method. :) Let me see if I can whip something up

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be as easy as

```
describe MyClass do 
  it 'should create something' do 
    expect(Something).to receive(:create)
    subject.subscribe

    subject.trigger_message # you should trigger a message somehow
  end
end
```

Comment: `redis.subscribe` is going to block the execution. Thus, this code is invalid

Answer (score -1):

Although this approach is not using actual tests, i would do the following and check the logs.

```
class MyClass
  def subscribe
    $redis.subscribe('channel') do |on|
       on.message do |channel, msg|
         event = Something.create(msg)
         p event.persisted? ? "success" : "fail"
         p event
       end
    end
  end
end
```