# How to test Redis Lock via Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rspec-rails

We have a `Lockable` concern that allows for locks via Redis

```
module Lockable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def redis_lock(key, options = {})
    Redis::Lock.new(
      key,
      expiration: options[:expiration] || 15,
      timeout: options[:timeout] || 0.1
    ).lock { yield if block_given? }
  end
end
```

We use this in a Controller method to ensure concurrent requests are handled correctly.

```
def create
  redis_lock(<generated_key>, timeout: 15) do
    # perform_operation
  end

  render json: <data>, status: :ok
end
```

When testing this action, I want to test that the correct `generated_key` is being sent to Redis to initiate a lock.

I set up an expect for the Redis::Lock but that returns false always presumably because the request to create is sent mid request and not at the end of it.

```
expect(Redis::Lock).to receive(:create).once
```

Test structure:

```
context 'return status ok' do
       When do
          post :create, params: {
            <params>
          }
        end
        Then {
          expect(Redis::Lock).to receive(:create).once
          response.ok?
        }
   end
end
```

---

Since the lock is cleared at the end of the method call, I cannot check for the key in redis as a test.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32782446/2651076) recommends setting up a fake class that matches the structure of Lockable to emulate the same behaviour but how do I write a test for it? The method we have does not return any value to verify.

Comment: expect(Redis::Lock).to receive (:new).with(key).and_call_original. written from mobile, syntax may vary slightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided I believe you just set up the wrong test:

```
expect(Redis::Lock).to receive(:create).once
```

This expects the `Redis::Lock` class to receive a `create` call, but you are calling `create` in your controller.

What you *are* doing in the `redis_lock` method is initializing an *instance* of `Redis::Lock` and calling `lock` on it. In my opinion, that is what you should test:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Redis::Lock).to receive(:lock).once
```

The **Implementation** would look something like this:

```
describe 'Lockable' do
  describe '#redis_lock' do
    subject { lockable.redis_lock(key, options) }

    # you gotta set this
    let(:lockable) { xyz }
    let(:key) { xyz } 
    let(:options) { x: 'x', y: 'y' }

    it 'calls Redis::Lock.new with correct arguments' do 
      expect(Redis::Lock).to receive(:new).with(key: key, options: options)
      subject
    end

    it 'calls #lock on the created Redis::Lock instance' do
      expect_any_instance_of(Redis::Lock).to receive(:lock).once
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I set up logger inside the `Redis::Lock` file inside `def lock`. The method gets called but the expectation still fails.

Comment: did you call the subject?

Comment: I often made the mistake of setting up the expectation but forgetting to call the subject ;)

Comment: I have updated the question with how the test is written. I did not understand your comment about calling the subject. Can you suggest if I am doing it right?

Comment: I edited the answer to include an example of how I'd implement it with rspec

Comment: This should work, but we aren't testing generated key in the spec. Which is the main thing to be tested as per OP

Comment: good point, I added that. I feel these tests could further be expanded, like testing that a second instance cannot access redis with the same key if it is still locked... But gotta take it one step after the other...

Answer (score 1):

This is modified version of [davegson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235594/davegson) using Rspec spies, This eliminates the coding smells like [any_instances_of](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333027/testing-why-expect-any-instance-of-is-considered-a-design-smell)

```
describe 'Lockable' do
  describe '#redis_lock' do
    it "delegates functionality to Redis::Lock with proper arguments" do
      # create an instance spy
      redis_lock = instance_spy("Redis::Lock")
      expect(Redis::Lock).to receive(:new).with('test', any_args).and_return(redis_lock)
      redis_lock('test', timeout: 15) do
        sleep 1
      end
      expect(redis_lock).to have_received(:lock)
    end
  end
end
```